# Set font in javafx

Tags: javafx

How to set font to a column in table view in java fx. I have a table with 3 columns and i want to set different fonts for each of the columns. Also, is it possible to change the font in runtime. Please help with some sample code.

Answer (score 14):

## **Changing the table column style:**

You should to use [TableColumn#setCellFactory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory%28javafx.util.Callback%29) to customize cell item rendering.
For example, datamodel with like this [Person class](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJADAHAH):

```
// init code vs..
TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
firstNameCol.setCellFactory(getCustomCellFactory("green"));

TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
lastNameCol.setCellFactory(getCustomCellFactory("red"));

table.setItems(data);
table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

// scene create code vs..
```

and the common `getCustomCellFactory()` method:

```
private Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>> getCustomCellFactory(final String color) {
        return new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, String> call(TableColumn<Person, String> param) {
                TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<Person, String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(final String item, boolean empty) {
                        if (item != null) {
                            setText(item);
                            setStyle("-fx-text-fill: " + color + ";");
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        };
    }
```

## **Changing the table column header style:**

`TableView` like other controls of JavaFX uses a built-in style sheet named `caspian.css` which is bundled with jfxrt.jar. See the [answer of "JavaFX 2 and CSS classes"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905730/682495).
To change the column font style you can either override the default style or customize it:
Overriding:

```
.table-view .column-header{
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
    -fx-font-size: 16;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
}
```

Customizing:

```
#my-custom .table-view .column-header {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
    -fx-font-size: 26;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
}
```

Overriding effects all `TableView`s in app. So if you prefer to customize then once you define multiple styles, you can apply the custom style to any tableview at runtime as,

```
myTableView.setId("my-custom");
...
// Apply another style at runtime
myTableView.setId("my-custom2");
```

To see how to define and load style sheet files to app, check out the [post of "JavaFX How to set scene background image"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9739698/682495).

However, applying different styles to different columns requires more effort I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was helpful. The above style applies for all column headers of the table. Is it possible to apply for each column. In your example .table-view .column-header{
    
} applies for all the column header. My question is what style (syntax) to specify that for column 1 use this stlye 1, column2 use style 2... .

Comment: I totally misunderstood your question my apologies :). Meanwhile I assume you have already done it but I edited my answer for future reference.

Comment: The current default CSS styling for JavaFX is `modena.css` starting with JavaFX 8, not `caspian.css`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fxml or css  file to set fonts color ......

```
 # .mainFxmlClass {
 -fx-font-family:nyala,Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;   
 -fx-font-size:1.13em;  
 }

 .label{
 -fx-font-size:1.3em;
  }
```

and call and use .lable or .mainFxmlClass in the fxml file

Answer (score -1):

> what style (syntax) to specify that for column 1 use this stlye 1, column2 use style 2

[Supply a custom cell factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory%28javafx.util.Callback%29) which supplies [cells](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) to which you have applied styleclasses you have defined in css.  The linked documentation contains examples which should provide you with enough information to achieve this.