# Remove gray bg behind the tabs in JFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

So is there any way to remove the gray area behind the tab(s):
[image: example]

I've tried to do this with CSS, but didn't find how.

Comment: have you played around with the component's opacity?

Comment: yes, opacity, background\foreground color, didnt' help

Comment: Here is an easier way `tabPane.getStyleClass().add("floating");`. Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17488304/1812434)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaFX has a built-in default CSS sheet named caspian.css. Please read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149050/682495.
To change the default CSS, add this selector to your CSS file and customize it:

```
.tab-pane *.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, derive(-fx-color, -20%);
    -fx-effect: innershadow(two-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 4, 0.0 , 0 , 0);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

To set the background color of the tabpane header write in the CSS file:

```
.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}
```

To remove the borders write:

```
.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```

To remove the header completely set opacity to 0:

```
.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

More on style class tab-pane you can find here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tabpane

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easier way tabPane.getStyleClass().add("floating"); (copied from a comment above that didn't get enough attention)