# JavaFX : Custom styling for multiple TabPanes

Tags: css, javafx, tabs

I have a TabPane for which I have set a style through CSS. However, I would like to have the different style fot the TabPane on another screen(for selected and unselected tabs). The following code is what I have working when I was using a common style for all the TabPane.

```
.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}

.tab-pane
{
    -fx-tab-min-width:90px;
}

.tab{
    -fx-background-insets: 0 1 0 1,0,0;
}
.tab-pane .tab
{
    -fx-background-color: #abe0ff;

}

.tab-pane .tab:selected
{
    -fx-background-color: #015A7C;
}

.tab .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: #3c3c3c;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.tab:selected .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    /* -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.833em; /* 5 2 0 10 */
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.0em; /* overridden as 5 2 0 0 */
}
```

In the case of trying to set it to different colors, I tried the following which was an unsuccessful attempt :

```
.MyTabPane > .tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}

.MyTabPane > .tab-pane
{
    -fx-tab-min-width:90px;
}

.MyTabPane > .tab{
    -fx-background-insets: 0 1 0 1,0,0;
}

.MyTabPane > .tab-pane .tab
{
    -fx-background-color: #e8e8e8;

}

.MyTabPane > .tab-pane .tab:selected
{
    -fx-background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.MyTabPane > .tab .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: #3c3c3c;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.MyTabPane > .tab:selected .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.MyTabPane > .tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    /* -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.833em; /* 5 2 0 10 */
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.0em; /* overridden as 5 2 0 0 */
}
```

This is from my FXML :

```
<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" GridPane.rowIndex="1" styleClass="MyTabPane">
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

I also tried following this idea, but couldn't get it through for the color of unselected tab: [How do you set JavaFX TabPane CSS in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908109/how-do-you-set-javafx-tabpane-css-in-code)

P.S. I am pretty new to CSS. I apologize if it is a silly question. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Would you like to change style when you select a `TabPane` or do you want to define different permanent styles for each tabpane, for example a blue tab and a yellow tab?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have 2 different permanent styles for both TabPanes.
For example. The frist TabPane in the shade of blue:
Selected Tab(dark blue tab-button background/ text color white) / Unselected Tab (Light blue tab-button background gray text).

Second TabPane in the shade of Yellow:
Selected Tab(dark yellow tab-button background/ text color white) / Unselected Tab (Light yellow tab-button background gray text)

Comment: please stick to naming conventions: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#intronaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anybody facing this issue can refer the following code. Turns out I was not using the selector correctly :

FXML :

```
<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" GridPane.rowIndex="1" styleClass="MyTabPane">
```

CSS :
.MyTabPane
{
-fx-tab-min-width:90px;
}

```
.tab{
    -fx-background-insets: 0 1 0 1,0,0;
}
.MyTabPane .tab
{
    -fx-background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.MyTabPane .tab:selected
{
    -fx-background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.tab .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: #3c3c3c;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.tab:selected .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.MyTabPane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.0em; /* overridden as 5 2 0 0 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple TabPane and add style class:

```
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.getStyleClass().add("MyTabPane");
    Tab tab1 = new Tab("Page 1", new Label("Page 1"));
    Tab tab2 = new Tab("Page 2", new Label("Page 2"));
    Tab tab3 = new Tab("Page 3", new Label("Page 3"));
    tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2, tab3);
```

In CSS:

```
.MyTabPane .tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}

.MyTabPane .tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-min-width: 90px;
}

.MyTabPane .tab {
    -fx-background-insets: 0 1 0 1, 0, 0;
}

.MyTabPane .tab-pane .tab {
    -fx-background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.MyTabPane .tab-pane .tab:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.MyTabPane .tab .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: #3c3c3c;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.MyTabPane .tab:selected .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}

.MyTabPane .tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    /* -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.833em; /* 5 2 0 10 */
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.0em; /* overridden as 5 2 0 0 */
}
```

Comment: This only changes the color of the text of the selected and unselected tabs,. I would like to change the background color of the tab (buttons - selected and unselected) as well.