# Selector for a custom class

Tags: css, javafx

Let's say I have a class called TextEditor which extends TextArea, so what's the right selector for this? Selector like `.text-editor` didn't help.

Well, actually `.text-area` works fine, but that's no the solution.

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome's inspector to examine the DOM and figure out what classes it has.

Comment: This is a desctop app, so no firebug/chrome or dom

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't aware of the Java classes that you have created.  Manually add a CSS class and use that to style it. E.g. class="TextEditor" then style it with .TextEditor

Answer (score 0):

You may define your own selector that customizes the default `.text-area` selector. And set the id of your custom class with this selector. See the "Changing the table column header style : Customzing" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149050/682495).