# JavaFX Table Cell Formatting

Tags: format, render, cell, javafx-2

```
    TableColumn<Event,Date> releaseTime  = new TableColumn<>("Release Time");
    releaseTime.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Event,Date>("releaseTime")
            );
```

How can I change the format of releaseTime? At the moment it calls a simple toString on the Date object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish that through Cell Factories. See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149050/682495
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10700642/682495
Although the 2nd link is about `ListCell`, the same logic is totally applicable to `TableCell`s too.

P.S. Still if you need some sample code, kindly will attach here.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to preserve the sorting capabilities of your TableColumn, none of the solutions above is valid: if you convert your Date to a String and show it that way in your TableView; the table will sort it as such (so incorrectly).

The solution I found was subclassing the Date class in order to override the toString() method. There is a caveat here though: the TableView uses java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date; so you need to subclass the former.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class CustomDate extends java.sql.Date {

    public CustomDate(long date) {
        super(date);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(this);
    }
}
```

The table will call that method in order to print the date.

Of course, you need to change too your Date class in the TableColumn declaration to the new subclass:

```
@FXML
TableColumn<MyObject, CustomDate> myDateColumn;
```

Same thing when you attach your object attribute to the column of your table:

```
myDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory< MyObject, CustomDate>("myDateAttr"));
```

And finally, for the shake of clarity this is how you declare the getter in your object class:

```
public CustomDate getMyDateAttr() {
    return new CustomDate(myDateAttr.getTime()); //myDateAttr is a java.util.Date           
}
```

It took me a while to figure out this due to the fact that it uses java.sql.Date behind the scenes; so hopefully this will save other people some time!

Answer (score 8):

Update for Java FX8:

(I'm not sure it is the good place for that answer, but I get the problem in JavaFX8 and some things have changed, like java.time package)

Some differences with the previous answers:
I keep the date type on the column, so I need to use both cellValueFactory and cellFactory.
I Make a generic reusable method to generate the cellFactory for all date columns.
I use java 8 date for java.time package! But the method could be easily reimplemented for java.util.date.

```
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<MyBeanUi, ZonedDateTime> dateColumn;

@FXML
public void initialize () {
  // The normal binding to column 
  dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCreationDate());

  //.. All the table initialisation and then
  DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT);
  dateColumn.setCellFactory (getDateCell(format));

}

public static <ROW,T extends Temporal> Callback<TableColumn<ROW, T>, TableCell<ROW, T>> getDateCell (DateTimeFormatter format) {
  return column -> {
    return new TableCell<ROW, T> () {
      @Override
      protected void updateItem (T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem (item, empty);
        if (item == null || empty) {
          setText (null);
        }
        else {
          setText (format.format (item));
        }
      }
    };
  };
}
```

The advantages are that:

- The column is typed with a "java8 Date" to avoid the sort problem evoqued by @Jordan
- The method "getDateCell" is generic and can be used as an util function for all Java8 Time types (Local Zoned etc.)

Comment: Yes, my experiments seem to show that even if you use a non-ISO date format (which sorts just like its `String` equivalent of course (2020-04-23, etc.)!) this leaves columns sortable by chronological order.

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend using Java generics to create re-usable column formatter that takes any `java.text.Format`. This cuts down on the amount of boilerplate code...

```
private class ColumnFormatter<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> {
    private Format format;

    public ColumnFormatter(Format format) {
        super();
        this.format = format;
    }
    @Override
    public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> arg0) {
        return new TableCell<S, T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(new Label(format.format(item)));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Examples of usage

```
birthday.setCellFactory(new ColumnFormatter<Person, Date>(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM YYYY")));
amplitude.setCellFactory(new ColumnFormatter<Levels, Double>(new DecimalFormat("0.0dB")));
```

Comment: but which property does is use? there is no property name in your sample.

Comment: @MaxiWu alongside the above setCellFactory(), you still need to call setCellValueFactory() to bind to an actual property

Answer (score 6):

I needed to do this recently -

```
dateAddedColumn.setCellValueFactory(
   new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Film, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
      @Override
      public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Film, String> film) {
         SimpleStringProperty property = new SimpleStringProperty();
         DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
         property.setValue(dateFormat.format(film.getValue().getCreatedDate()));
         return property;
      }
   });
```

However - it is a *lot* easier in Java 8 using Lamba Expressions:

```
dateAddedColumn.setCellValueFactory(
   film -> {
      SimpleStringProperty property = new SimpleStringProperty();
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      property.setValue(dateFormat.format(film.getValue().getCreatedDate()));
      return property;
   });
```

Hurry up with that Java 8 release oracle!

Comment: This works fine for initially populating the table...if the date property in the model changes later than the SimpleStringProperty does not emit a notification, and the table is not updated.

Answer (score 3):

An universal solution could be as simple as that:

```
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public interface AbstractConvertCellFactory<E, T> extends Callback<TableColumn<E, T>, TableCell<E, T>> {

    @Override
    default TableCell<E, T> call(TableColumn<E, T> param) {
        return new TableCell<E, T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(convert(item));
                }
            }
        };
    }

    String convert(T value);        
}
```

And its sample usage:

```
TableColumn<Person, Timestamp> dateCol = new TableColumn<>("employment date");
dateCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("emploumentDateTime"));    
dateCol.setCellFactory((AbstractConvertCellFactory<Person, Timestamp>) value -> new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(value));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what i did and i worked perfectly.

```
tbColDataMovt.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Auditoria, Timestamp> column) -> {
    return new TableCell<Auditoria, Timestamp>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Timestamp item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.toLocalDateTime().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pipe Properties of different type and put a formatter or converter in between.

```
    //from my model
    ObjectProperty<Date> valutaProperty;

    //from my view
    TableColumn<Posting, String> valutaColumn;

    valutaColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            cellData -> {
                  SimpleStringProperty property = new SimpleStringProperty();
                  property.bindBidirectional(cellData.getValue().valutaProperty,  new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN));
                  return property;
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `StringConverter` classes are another mechanism.

`TextFieldTableCell` has a constructor as follows: `public TextFieldTableCell(StringConverter<T> converter)`.

... and `StringConverter`s consist of subclasses such as `LocalDateStringConverter`. A default implementation would then be:

```
new TextFieldTableCell( new LocalDateStringConverter() );
```

... this is not bad, but the parameter-less `LocalDateStringConverter` uses dates of the format 'dd/mm/yyyy' both for parsing (`fromString()` method) and `toString()`. But there are other constructors where you can pass a `FormatStyle` or `DateTimeFormatter`.

From my experiments, however, `StringConverter`s are slightly problematic in that it is difficult to catch the `DateTimeParseException` thrown by `fromString()` with an invalid date.

This can be remedied by creating your own `StringConverter` class, e.g.:

```
class ValidatingLocalDateStringConverter extends LocalDateStringConverter {
    boolean valid;

    @Override
    LocalDate fromString(String value) {
        valid = true;
        if (value.isBlank()) return null;
        try {
            // NB wants ISO
            return LocalDate.parse( value );
        } catch ( DateTimeParseException e) {
            valid = false;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    String toString( LocalDate date ){
        // NB returns ISO or the String "null" with null date value (!)
        String s = date.toString();
        return s.equals( 'null' )? '' : s;
    }
}
```

Using this `StringConverter` solution will mean that dates are sorted according to chronological order, regardless of the `String` representation.