# Rendering table column in "dd/mm/yyyy" format

Tags: java, date, javafx

How do I render my table column to make the dates inside (date format) formatted to "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Table column:

```
tcBirthday.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Birthday"));
```

Note that "Birthday" gets all its dates from a MySQL database, and I'm using a JavaFX tableview.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18728726/905488), which uses a custom [`Callback`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Callback.html) along with `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting, might help.

Comment: This helped me fix the format! thanks!