# MySQL Date Format in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I have a JavaFX TableView representing job data that is populated by a MySQL database. All the data displays fine except two date columns, both of which are represented YYYY-MM-DD. What I would like to do is have this the other way around i.e DD-MM-YYYY.

```
+--------------+------------+
| Date Created |  Deadline  |
+--------------+------------+
| 2015-09-07   | 2015-09-14 |
| 2015-09-07   | 2015-09-14 |
+--------------+------------+
```

Would it be best to do this by modifying the MySQL query I use to populate the table: `final String finalQuery = "SELECT * FROM kitJobs ORDER BY kitJobs.CaseNO ASC";` ? If so, how would I modify the query to get the desired date format?

Comment: Are you storing the date information in text fields in the database? If so, I'd change *that* first, if at all possible. Then, change how the information is formatted within JavaFX - don't change the query. (It should be the UI that determines the format, not the data layer.)

Comment: @JonSkeet they are stored as date types in the database. How would I go about changing the formatting of the data from within JavaFX?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412360/javafx-table-cell-formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat;

```
  String s;
  Format formatter;
  Date date = new Date();

  // 01/09/02
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  s = formatter.format(date);
  System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this solution is when do I apply the format to the date and how would it be applied to the JavaFX table column? I tried formatting after getting the date from the database but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference for anyone else seeking a similar solution I successfuly formatted my columns in the UI by doing the following;

```
deadlineDateCol.setCellValueFactory(
           Job -> {
              SimpleStringProperty property = new SimpleStringProperty();
              DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
              property.setValue(dateFormat.format(Job.getValue().getDeadlineDate()));
              return property;
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and i worked perfectly.

```
tbColDataMovt.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Auditoria, Timestamp> column) -> {
  return new TableCell<Auditoria, Timestamp>() {
     @Override
     protected void updateItem(Timestamp item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
         if (item == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
         } 
         else {
            setText(item.toLocalDateTime().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
         }
      }
   };
});
```