# JavaFX HTML formatter

Tags: java, html, format, javafx

I'm developing an application for creating quizzes. A quiz have more questions. A question look like this:

```
  <p>How are you<p>
  <b>How old are you</b>
  What is your name?
```

You see that I've used html tags. How can I format a question? If the question is between `<b>`'s, the font must be bold. If the font-family is "Arial", the font from the UI must be "Arial".

Comment: you can provide a css to format it, similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147325/set-font-in-javafx/10149050#10149050

Answer (score 0):

Display your questions in a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) and use [html](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/) and [html compatible css](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/) to markup the content.

---

If you don't have to use html for markup, you could instead:

Place multiple [Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) objects in a [FlowPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html) and style them with [JavaFX css](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

OR

In Java 8+, use the [TextFlow](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/Rich+Text+API+Samples) control.