# joda time parse method return format

Tags: java, jodatime

I have very simple question - I read couple of threads here but I still do not understand how to get simple thing. I want to send string to method and get back joda date. I had no problem to build it up, but return format is 2015-03-11T17:13:09:000+01:00. How can I get desired (e.g. mmm-dd hh:mm) format back from below mentioned method (it mustto be a dateTime for sorting purposes on FX form)? I tried to gamble with another dateTimeFormatter but had no luck. Thank you very much in advance

```
public static DateTime stringToDateTime(String textDate) throws ParseException
{
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    DateTime jodaTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(textDate);

    return jodaTime;
}
```

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "return format"? "Format" term here could only be related to a string representation of a `DateTime` object. That means you should specify format of your input string (what you've already done in your code) - and a corresponding `DateTime` object will be created. After that you probably use `toString()` to check the results, but `DateTime.toString()` uses ISO8601 format (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ) according to [JavaDoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toString()) - that gives you your `2015-03-11T17:13:09:000+01:00` result.

So to get it as desired you could try using `toString(String pattern)` method with format you need. But once again - it's just an output format to convert `DateTime` to `String`, it **doesn't** affect the datetime stored in your `DateTime` object.

Comment: HIi FlasH. thx for yourfeedback.I will try to describe a bit more entire setup. I am pulling data into recordset from MS SQL DB, this particular column is in DateTime format. I am looping the recordset, this column as DateFormater.stringToDateTime(rs.getString("Date_Sent") - using the above method. This is then binded in controller of my form designed in scene builder as @FXML private TableColumn<Email, DateTime> emailReceivedColumn and emailReceivedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("dateReceived")). I cant overide toString, can you expain a bit more your suggestion? thx!

Comment: I'm not familiar with javaFX, but it seems to me that you actually _can_ override format for the column - use cell factories. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147325/set-font-in-javafx/10149050#10149050
I.e. from my understanding you should define you own cell factory and implement your own `updateItem(..)` method to print `DateTime` in correct format.

Comment: hi once again Flash. I will take a look on this, I am just starting with Java so things which might seems to be very easy in my eyes, such as change date format, are at the end quite complex things.

Answer (score 0):

I just use Calendar object so this is a possible way to do it:

```
    static String stringToDateTime(String textDate) {

    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    // How you want the input to be formatted
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = df.parse(textDate);
        c.setTime(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // How do you want to print your date
    df= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
    return df.format(c.getTime());
}

// input
    String myDate = "2015-04-15 14:25:25";
    System.out.println(stringToDateTime(myDate));
```